# Error in FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android

i have a 5 activity

1 >> 2 >> 3 >> 4 >> 5

the number 1 activity is first launch class.

number 2 is my list data class

number 3 and 4 is my input data class

number 5 is finishing class

in activity number 5 i put code in button to come back to previous when finished

i have two button back to previous activity.

1. back to activity number 2
2. back to activity number 1

here is button on number 5 activity

1).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 2.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                startActivity(intent);
```

2).

```
Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 1.class);
                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(dashboard);
```

**EDIT**

**a**. when i choose button number **2).** in first build application, i click and back to number 1 activity. when I tap the back button , the activity not show number 5 activity again and it works.

senario **a** : 1 >> 2>> 3 >> 4 >> 5 >> 1 >> exit app

**b**. when i choose button number **2).** in first build application, i try to input data again and at last in number 5 activity, i choose button number **1).** i click and back to number 2 activity . when I tap the back button , the activity not shows number 5 activity again and it works.

senario **b** : 1 >> 2 >> 3 >> 4 >> 5 >> 1 >> 2 >> 3 >> 4 >> 5 >> 2 >> tap back button >> 1 >> tap back button >> exit app

**c**. but when i choose button number **1).** in first build application. i click and back to number 2 activity. when I tap the back button , it shows Previous activity again or activity number 5.

senario **c** : 1 >> 2 >> 3 >> 4 >> 5 >> 2 >> tap back button >> 5

**d**. i want my button number **1).** not show previous or activity number 5 when i tap the back button in my first build application or the last activity is not show without i choose button number **2).** first.

scenario **d** : 1 >> 2 >> 3 >> 4 >> 5 >> 2 >> tap back button >> 1 >> exit app

how to fix that?

problem since yesterday till now

sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT**

in my manifest i declare

number 1 activity is MainMenu.class .

```
<activity
            android:name="hariff.ltis.mainmenu.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

number 2 is MainPetakTetap.class

```
<activity
            android:name="hariff.ltis.petaktetap.MainPetakTetap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_petak_tetap" >
        </activity>
```

activity number 3, 4, 5

```
<activity
            android:name="hariff.ltis.petaktetap.MainUpdate"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_petak_tetap" >
        </activity>

<activity
            android:name="hariff.ltis.petaktetap.UpdateLog"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_petak_tetap" >
        </activity>

<activity
            android:name="hariff.ltis.petaktetap.CPetakTempView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_petak_tetap" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: How do you declare Activity 1 in manifest

Comment: I mean Activity 2, and do you set any flag when launching 2 from 1?

Comment: declare all 5 activity here .

Comment: The only way I can see it is activity 2 is killed by the system and when you call from 5 it is put on top of 5. Try to go though the activity quickly and see if you get the same thing.

Comment: Did you set any flag when launching 2 from 1 and/or do you call finish  in 2 when launching 3, 4 or 5?

Comment: no flag between 1 to 2. no flag and finish between 2 and 3. no flag but finish between 3 and 4 . 5 is flag to 1 and 2 @HoanNguyen

Comment: Does this happen all the time? I think 2 is killed by the system. Move the buttons in 5 to 3 and test to see if the same thing happen.

Comment: ok i'll try . @HoanNguyen then i show the result.

Comment: Call finish in 5 and see if back press on 2 go to 3 or 4. If that is the case then 2 is definitely killed by the system.

Comment: i put `onBackPressed()` in 3 and 4 activity. i use button `finish()` only, then show number 4 activity. when i put finish() inside my intent to intent activity 2, the back press on still on 4 activity? what should i do? @HoanNguyen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27527/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-alex-belek)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the system kill activity 2 and thus 2 is not in the stack anymore, thus it is now created anew and on top of 5. Thus when you back press you will get 5. A work around (I am not sure it will work) is as follow

1. When starting activity 4 from activity 3 and activity 5 from 4 use startActivityForResult.
2. In activity 4

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
   {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
       {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
       }
   }
   ```
3. In Activity 3

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
   {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
       {
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 2.class);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
           startActivity(intent);
            finish();
       }
   }
   ```
4. In activity 5

   ```
   setResult(RESULT_OK);
   finish();
   ```

Comment: number 4 in your question is still in activity 3 or 4?

Comment: number 3 is activity 4 and number 4 is activity 3. I will edit the answer.

Comment: `RESULT_CANCELED` ? still stuck on 4 activity when i back press

Comment: why in activity 3 the intent to 2 activity?how about activity 4? i use result_ok to starting activity 4.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27547/discussion-between-alex-belek-and-hoan-nguyen)

Answer (score 0):

if you are going back from any activity to last activity.

please use `finish()` instead of creating new `Intent`

IN your code ,you are creating new Intent for activity `1.class`,which is already exist .this is wrong

```
Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 1.class);
                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(dashboard);
```

do this on button click

`finish();` //this will finish your current activity which is in stack.

and try to use `this` or `current activity name instead of`getApplicationContext()`.

**update :**
if you want to go any activity just use `StartActivityForResult()`

Comment: `finish();` return to number 4 activity

Comment: then use startActivityForResult().

Comment: can you please update in your question ..your scenario  like A->B->C and C->A something like that